How to switch the order of two keys in OpenAPI YAML generated by Rswag?
In Swagger UI, there's a bug with allOf and nested associations which causes those parts of the schemas to not be included:

swagger example response not respecting nested allOf
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5972
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/2765

The solution is to put paths: before components: in your OpenAPI YAML.  I tested it, and this works.
So, how can I get Rswag to generate in this order whenever I run rails rswag?
I would be fine with just modifying the file immediately after generation.  But I need it to be generated in this order for things to work

@engineersmnky the yml does generate, but with components: before :paths, which mangles some of the swagger-ui presentation.  I'm saying I would be fine with the file being modified programmatically as part of running the command if that's what's workable.

Have you tried using the swagger_filter to reorder the keys? E.g. pop the components key and then append it at the very end.

Thanks to @Helen for recommending this approach:
# config/initializers/rswag_api.rb

Rswag::Api.configure do |c|
  c.swagger_filter = lambda { |swagger, env| 
    # Remove the 'components' key and store its value
    components = swagger.delete('components')

    # Reinsert the 'components' key at the end
    swagger['components'] = components
  }
end

This solution works despite not changing the yml.  So it addresses the core issue which is in Swagger UI.  Thanks for the help.
